# Sort array containing objects based on another array using _Underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I already read the previous questions answered, but it didn't fit with my need.

I have an array of objects such as

```
var Widgets = [
             [{Id: 'abcdef', post_id: 12345}],
             [{Id: 'ghijkl', post_id: 45678}],
             [{Id: 'mnoptq', post_id: 90123}]
];
```

I have a second array :

```
var sortArray = ['ghijkl', 'mnoptq', 'abcdef'];
```

I need To reorder Widgets with the initial order of elements which appears on sortArray

i've succeed to do it this way

```
sortArray.forEach(function(Id) {
                    var found = false;                  
                    Widgets = Widgets.filter(function(Widget) {
                        if(!found && Widget.Id == Id) {
                            NewWidgets.push(Widget);
                            found = true;
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                });
```

But I wish to improve this code by using _SortBy but I didn't succeed so far...

Anyhelp ?

**Edit**

Final result should be

```
var Widgets = [
             [{Id: 'ghijkl', post_id: 45678}],
             [{Id: 'mnoptq', post_id: 90123}],
             [{Id: 'abcdef', post_id: 12345}]
];
```

Comment: This is unclear, the array has no order, it's all the same ?

Comment: @Toucouleur what result do you want ?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake on copy/paste, info added

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
sorted = _.sortBy(Widgets, function(x) {
    return _.indexOf(sortArray, x[0].Id)
})
```

This is not very efficient, a faster way is to convert `sortArray` to an object `key=>index` and use hash lookups in `sortBy`:

```
sortObj = _.invert(_.object(_.pairs(sortArray)));

sorted = _.sortBy(Widgets, function(x) {
    return sortObj[x[0].Id]
})
```

Comment: Works like a charm even if I made this change to fit with my needs :
`sortArray = _.invert(_.object(_.pairs(sortArray)));`

`Widgets = _.sortBy(Widgets, function(Widget) {`
  `return sortArray[Widget.objectId];`
`});`

Comment: I had to add `parseInt` to make this work properly. I'm pretty sure it's because my sort array was > 10 items and the sortObj was a collection of strings. So: `return parseInt(sortObj[x[0].Id]), 10)`

Answer (score 0):

On top of @georg's solution, if performance is really important to you, and you have to keep something like this<sup>1</sup>, then preparing the key/index object using the following will be much faster:

```
// Example: ['a', 'b', 'c'] becomes { 'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2 }
var sortObj = sortArray.reduce(function(acc, value, index) {
  acc[value] = index;
  return acc;
}, {});

// Same as posted by @georg, with no need for `parseInt`
sorted = _.sortBy(Widgets, function(Widget) {
  return sortObj[Widget[0].Id];
});
```

It's a bit longer but also I'd argue it's also easier to read than the `invert`/`object`/`pairs`.

Also, note that there is no need for `parseInt` with this solution, because it builds an object of integer values, while the other solution returns strings.

<sup>1</sup> Because let's face it, there are other ways to improve this if you actually can give it a bigger refactor.